# Nginx as Reverse Proxy for Apache

Tags: apache, nginx

Ive been reading on using Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache and how i can get benefits from using both. I dot have much experience with nginx, so im hoping someone here with more experience can take a look at my configuration and let me know if its a good starting point/where it can be improved.

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
# Here, we have told that we are to listen to any request made to port 80 & then redirect it to https.  
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl;
# This is the document root
root /var/www/html/;
# This is the file which gets loaded by default. index.html gets loaded if there is no index.php
index index.html index.htm index.php;
# This has to be the domain you want to use
server_name mysite.xyz;       
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.xyz/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.xyz/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS;
# Reverse Proxy
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:444;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
# This configuration prevent the logger to log not found robots.txt
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# This tells the Nginx server to rewrite any requests which do not access a valid file to rewrite on to the index.php
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
# This configuration prevent the logger to log not found favicon
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# This says that all files with the given endings should be cached by the client
location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg)$ {
            expires 365d;
}
# .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc, will not be served.
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
# hotlink protect your images and other file types
location ~ .(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|css|js|ico)$ {
    valid_referers none blocked mysite.xyz www.mysite.xyz;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a very broad question. Perhaps you could break it down into the specific things you want to accomplish. Alternatively you could try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below nginx configuration to run nginx as reverse proxy for apache

```
server {
       listen 443 ssl;

       server_name www.example.com example.com;

       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
       ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
        location /.git {
            deny all;
            return 404;
        }
}
```

restart nginx server after modification